# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

An error occurs when I try to get beneficiaries through "get_beneficiary",I do not understand what that means,If there is a problem with the following code, please let me know to fix it.

```
views


class ListView(ResponseViewMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = CourseFilterSerializer
    queryset = Course.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, common_data=None):
        if common_data:
            common_data = common_data
        else:
            common_data = Course.objects.all()
            print(common_data)

        course_beneficiaries = get_beneficiary(common_data)
 response_data = {
            "course_beneficiaries": course_beneficiaries,
        }
        return response_data



def get_beneficiary(data):
    ben_details = []
    beneficiary = Beneficiary.objects.all()
    beneficiaries = CourseBeneficiarySerializer(beneficiary, many=True)
    for ben in beneficiaries.data:
        count = data.filter(beneficiary=ben['id']).count()
        count_data = {
            'name': ben['beneficiary_name'],
            'count': count
        }
        ben_details.append(count_data)
    return ben_details
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace? It might help understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting data from models,

```
 count_data = {
                'name': ben['beneficiary_name'],
                'count': count
            }
```

should be like

```
count_data = {
            'name': ben.values('beneficiary_name'),
            'count': count
        }
```